# passing dynamic text box to jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i have one php page where i generate textboxes from php and mysql table like

```
$sql="select * from product where pstatus=1";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    for($i=1;$i<=mysql_num_rows($result);$i++)
    {
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
      ?>
 <input class="text_field1" id="<?php echo $i ?>" name="q_<?php echo $row['pid']; ?>" type="text" />
<?Php
}
?>
```

what i want is, to get values of textboex in JQuery to to process like this....

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "add_pro.php",
 data: "cont_email="+ encodeURIComponent(cont_email) 
+"&caccount="+ encodeURIComponent(caccount)
...............
```

where cont_email & caccount but in place of ........ i need to get values of these dynamic textboxs but total number of boxes depends upon database.

Thanks

Comment: Please fix the spelling/grammar errors in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how you want the data separated/formated but you could do something like:

```
var totalContent = '';

$('input .text_field1').each(function(){
    totalContent += $(this).val() + '\n';
});

....
```